# Entering the UK with a Family Permit

Tags: uk

I have applied for a family permit (wife is Italian, I am Brazilian), as my wife accepted a job offer in the UK. My question is, do we need to travel together, or can I go before her to set up a place for us and our kids? And, do we need to enter the UK by an airport pr can I use a train or ferry from Europe?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot go before her.  She can go before you, or you can go together.  See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility:

> The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:
>
> - be in the UK already
> - be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application

You can enter the UK through any border control point.